# Ways to implement a "Thumbs down/Thumbs up" toggle button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement where I need to implement a thumbs up, thumbs down type of toggle button and I am struggling here to perceive how to accomplish this.
I am not sure if I could create a style and this style would have a  where it would change the background of the image depending of how the button is pressed....

Anyone could share some ideas?

Regards,
Felipe

**UPDATE:**

Hey guys
Following the ideas given here, I implemented the following code:

```
tglBtnThumbsUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tglBtnThumbsDown.setChecked(false);
            tglBtnThumbsUp.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
    tglBtnThumbsDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tglBtnThumbsUp.setChecked(false);
            tglBtnThumbsDown.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
```

It works just the way I want.
Now, trying to find a "thumbs up" and "thumbs down" PSD files in the Internet so I can change the background, as I am a very very very bad designer and can't do myself

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You might try extending `Button` and putting an image in it of a thumb up or down, then having the two of them modify a `SharedPreference` with an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` attached. The shared preference listener would modify the background, and button listeners would store to shared preferences and enable/disable each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean two toggle buttons side-by-side where the user turns one of them on, or do you mean one toggle that goes either up or down?

For just one togglebutton, use a selector in XML with the picture of an up thumb and a down thumb as state_checked="true" or false respectively. Otherwise put two different toggle buttons side by side, and have one of them light up or not at a time with OnCheckedChangeListener.

Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar with a refresh button and a Progress Bar.  In xml, I have the refresh button visible and the progressbar visibility:gone

```
    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/ivSync"
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh_dark" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbSync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```

Then, in code, I create OnClickListner events for each and toggle the visibilty of each control:

```
//Setup control listeners for Click events.
pbProgress.setOnClickListener(pbProgressBarClick);
ivSync.setOnClickListener(ivSyncClick);

private OnClickListener pbProgressBarClick = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Make the Sync image visible.
        ivSync.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Some other code here...

        //Make the ProgressBar invisible.
        pbProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
    }

};

private OnClickListener ivSyncClick = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Make the Sync image invisible.
        ivSync.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //Some other code here...

        //Make the ProgressBar visible.         
        pbProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

hope it helps!